# Are Repeater Book listings for Florida accurate?

Tags: repeater

I am trying to set up my minimal ham station at my new QTH in central FL.  I am interested in 2M & 440 FM repeaters at the moment.

I have used both chirp and the RT systems software to program memories in my HT.

In the lists I downloaded from RepeaterBook.com using the software and using the website, I notice the majority of 2M and 440 repeaters have the Tone Mode listed as T SQL  (tone squelch)...

I know that is not correct for a local repeater and some poking around the internet leaves me to believe that may not be correct for other listings.

Can anyone comment on the validity of the Repeater Book data?

Comment: Isn't there another listing of repeaters? If you find one you can compare that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what repeater book you are looking at, but the official repeater coordinator for Florida is https://fasma.org/ and the listings there should be accurate.

If they are not, it could be the repeater has recently changed settings or is (temporarily?) misconfigured or they didn't report the correct settings to FASMA.

Similarly, it could be the book you are using is out of date and things have changed since it was published.  You didn't mention which repeater(s?) you are having problems with, so I can't guess the real issue.

Comment: I have done more digging.  And, the objective was to find what FM repeaters I could access from my current location.  I downloaded several files from RepeaterBook containing repeater data for sites within 30 miles of my QTH. The lists of 2M/440 machine that I downloaded via chirp and the RTSytems software showed most of the repeaters using TSQL as the tone mode.  When I tried to access the closest repearer, it did not respond.  When I changed the tone mode to "Tone," it worked. I have tried to access other repeaters and failed.. More testing is required before I have have any real data. Tnx!

Comment: And, the fasma.org data shows the same tone mode.  I suspect they provide the FL data to RepeaterBook.  I will report my findings after more testing.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting what is happening.  Most repeaters with TSQL don't put tone on repeater beeps, etc. , but it might actually be working.   You can't tell unless someone is actually talking on the repeater (other than you).  Turn on TSQL, and you don't get IDs and courtesy tones so you can keep it on scan and not get lots of noise.  If you like courtesy tones, switch to T instead of TSQL and hear them.  My radio lets me do this in one button so...